# jQuery source file not getting included when php code is added

Tags: php, jquery

The code was working nicely , but after i added the below php code it all went down. It says "failed to load resource " for jquery-1.11.3.js after i added php code as shown below.
I m totally lost here. No idea whats wrong here.

```
<?php
    $currentMonthInInteger = date("n");
    $currentYear = date("Y");

    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonthInInteger, 1, $currentYear);

    $totalday = date("t", $timestamp);
    $thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
    $firstday = $thismonth['wday'] - 1;

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>CALENDAR</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

            <style>

                table{
                    position: relative;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 700px;
                    table-layout: fixed;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                }

                td{
                    display: inline;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    position: static;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: 1.5em;
                    padding: 12px 20px;
                    height: 57px;
                }

                #head{
                    height: 57px;
                }
                caption{
                    font-size: 2.2em;
                }

            </style>    
        </head>


    <body>

        <div id="main" align = "center">
            <table id="ref">
            <!--<tr>-->
                <caption id="month">JULY</caption>
            <!--</tr>-->

                    <tr id="head">
                        <th>MON</th>
                        <th>TUE</th>
                        <th>WED</th>
                        <th>THU</th>
                        <th>FRI</th>
                        <th>SAT</th>
                        <th>SUN</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 0>00</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 1>01</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 2>02</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 3>03</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 4>04</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 5>05</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 6>06</span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 7>07</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 8>08</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 9>09</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 10>10</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 11>11</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 12>12</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 13>13</span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 14>14</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 15>15</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 16>16</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 17>17</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 18>18</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 19>19</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 20>20</span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 21>21</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 22>22</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 23>23</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 24>24</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 25>25</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 26>26</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 27>27</span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 28>28</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 29>29</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 30>30</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 31>31</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 32>32</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 33>33</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 34>34</span></td>

                    <tr>
                        <td><span id = 35>35</span></td>
                        <td><span id = 36>36</span></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>


                        <br><br>
                        <button onclick = previousMonth()>Previous Month</button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button onclick = nextMonth()>Next Month</button>

            </div>


        </body>
    </html>
        <script>...
</script>
```

Comment: Thats not the case..i checked...the problem is jquery library not getting loaded in the page.

Comment: What error code is it getting when it tries to load jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

First, check if folder **include** is in the same directory as your **php** file, e.g.:

```
\include\jquery-1.11.3.js
\index.php
```

Javascript tag **src** path is relative to the location of html/php file that references it, or it can be relative to the root of your php site, depending on your configuration. So, if your file structure is as above, but still not loading, then try to include directory above **include** into **src** path, e.g. try different ways:

```
<script src="include/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="/include/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="../include/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="[DIRECTORY]/include/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use jQuery CDN to load jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

For other jQuery versions and related projects see: [jQuery CDN](http://code.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Thanxx buddies, I got the answer .It was all because of read permission not given for the jquery lib file.